# AVAudioPlayer : waiting for a sound to finish playing

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to play a sound file **and wait for it to finish** before exiting the function that calls *AVAudioPlayer.Play()*.

I understand that there is a *FinishedPlaying* EventHandler that could be initialized and will be called accordingly.

But the method must wait without bloking the main thread...
How could this be achived?

**EDIT 1**:

I've tried using a [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent) but the delegate FinishedPlaying on the AVAudioPlayer instance is never called at the end of the playback...

```
NSError err;
ManualResetEvent playSoundFinished = new ManualResetEvent(false);    
var currentPlayer = new AVAudioPlayer(soundResource, "mp3", out err);
currentPlayer.FinishedPlaying += delegate { playSoundFinished.Set();};
currentPlayer.Play();
// This call should block until the event is set
DispatchQueue.DefaultGlobalQueue.DispatchSync(() => playSoundFinished.WaitOne(-1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate is never called because the call to DispatchQueue.DefaultGlobalQueue.DispatchSync blocks the main thread.

The solution is to use a CancellationToken (or ManualResetEvent for that matter
) that is canceled in the delegate and waited outside the method that plays the sound.

Pseudo Code:

**Playing the sound**

```
NSError err;
this.currentPlayer = new AVAudioPlayer(soundResource, "mp3", out err);
this.waitFinishedPlaying = new CancellationTokenSource();
this.currentPlayer.FinishedPlaying = delegate {waitFinishedPlaying.Cancel();};
this.currentPlayer.NumberOfLoops = looping ? -1 : 0;
this.currentPlayer.PrepareToPlay();
if (delay != 0)
{
    this.currentPlayer.PlayAtTime(this.currentPlayer.DeviceCurrentTime + delay);
}
else
{
    this.currentPlayer.Play();
}
```

Outside the method that contains the code above:

```
try
{
    // The TimeSpan duration must be greater than the duration of the longuest sound to be played.
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), this.audioService.GetFinishedPlayingToken()).ConfigureAwait(true);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
}
```

**GetFinishedToken()** returns the waitFinishedPlaying instance initiated in the first block of code above.

The only limitation to this solution is that the caller method must be async to await the Task.

Answer (score 0):

[ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=net-7.0#examples) maintains a boolean variable in memory. When the boolean variable is `false` then it blocks all threads and when the boolean variable is `true` it unblocks all threads. You can control the initial state of a [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=net-7.0) by passing a Boolean value to the constructor: `true` if the initial state is signaled, and `false` otherwise.

You can solve the problem by changing it as below:

`ManualResetEvent playSoundFinished = new ManualResetEvent(true);`